# Taking the elements that are > 0 from 1 array to another

Tags: c++

I make the user to type maximum elements and then enter that elements into first array `p`,then I want to take only the elements that are bigger than 0 and transfer them to a new array `w`. Here's the code and where exactly I make mistake:

```
void main(){
    int p[10], w[10], n,i,j;
    cout << "Maximum elements: "; cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Enter " << i << "-nd element"; cin >> p[i];
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (p[i] > 0){
            w[j] = p[i];
            j++;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << w[j];
        }

    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: if w and p ar the same size, why do you need to use j? Use i only.

Comment: This is not a question to ask here. This is a too elementary operation. If you don't know how to do such an operation, I recommend you to read a beginners book on programming.

Comment: @hagubear What if the first non zero element is in the 3rd place?

Comment: A vector should be used for w.

Comment: @Aleksandar There are legitimate reasons for using a vector here, and also legitimate reasons for not doing so. Regardless, using a vector would have no impact on the question: the problem would be the same.

Comment: I didnt read anywhere that I am not allowed to post here a question  for beginners since I am a beginner ..... Whateva..

Comment: What is the problem exactly? And don't worry, this *is* the place for this kind of questions.

Comment: when I compile it it shows some other numbers like "3-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460"

Comment: @Huntix What do you think `for (j = 0; j < n; j++){ cout << w[j]; }` is doing there?

Comment: You did not initialize the arrays. You have to set 0 to all the elements of the vector, before beginning the process. Otherwise they will have random numbers in it.

Comment: @Jefffrey Well I think its gonna show the elements of w[j] from the 0 element to n

Comment: @Jefffrey Well he initializes p, but not w. Also he puts just some of the elements of p int w. And prints the entire array. But yes it is the problem in the printing loop.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (p[i] > 0){
        w[j] = p[i];
        j++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        cout << w[j];
    }

}
```

the inner loop is printing every element of the array `w`. That loop is executed for every element of `p` (being it inside the outer `for` loop).

This mean that, for example, the first time it visits `p` to check if the first element is `0`, it may assign `w[0]` and then go on and print all the elements of `w`. Problem is that `w` is not initialised at that point, so what you see is random garbage (probably).

Just move the loop outside and make it so it only prints the part of the array that is populated:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (p[i] > 0){
        w[j] = p[i];
        j++;
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
    cout << w[k];
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c60f368cb4e7dee)

Also learn how to use `std::vector` or `std::array` and the algorithms in `<algorithm>`.

Also remember that `main` has return type `int`.

Comment: I did as you said I get the numbers diffrent from 0 but again these number after it :   22-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460

Comment: @Huntix Can you show me the code that you are running?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){
 int p[10], w[10], n,i,k;
 cout << "Max elements: "; cin >> n;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  cout << "Enter " << i << "-nd Element"; cin >> p[i];
 }
 k = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  if (p[i] > 0){
   w[k] = p[i];
   k++;
  }
 }
  for (k = 0; k < n; k++){
   cout << w[k];
  }


 system("pause");

}`

Comment: @Huntix You have `k < n`, but this answer has `k < j` in the final loop. That's the point: you don't want to print *all* `n` elements of that array, but only those `j` elements that have had values assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::copy_if` from `<algorithm>` do the job you want, as in the example provided in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/:

```
// copy_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy_if, std::distance
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo = {25,15,5,-5,-15};
  std::vector<int> bar (foo.size());

  // copy only positive numbers:
  auto it = std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), [](int i){return !(i<0);} );
  bar.resize(std::distance(bar.begin(),it));  // shrink container to new size

  std::cout << "bar contains:";
  for (int& x: bar) std::cout << ' ' << x;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

For you code, the problem is that you modify `j` in the printing loop whereas it is primary used as output index. Try to reduce scope of your local variable to out spot those issues, creating sub function may also help.

Finnaly, your fixed code may be something like:

```
void main(){
    std::cout << "Maximum elements: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int p[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        std::cout << "Enter " << i << "-nd element";
        std::cin >> p[i];
    }
    int w[10];
    int w_size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (p[i] > 0){
            w[w_size] = p[i];
            w_size++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < w_size; i++){
        std::cout << w[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```